# iOS simulator using developer tools via ios_webkit_proxy_debug

Tags: ios, google-chrome, debugging, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to use ios_webkit_proxy_debug to use the Chrome dev tools with the ios simulator. I'm on OS X Mavericks. I used `brew install ios-webkit-proxy-debug`. If I type `brew list`, the three required items (libplist, libimobiledevice, and usbmuxd) for the proxy to work are there. All three are upgraded to the latest version.

I put this into the terminal to run the simulator:

```
SIM_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
"$SIM_DIR/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator" \
-SimulateApplication \
$SIM_DIR/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari
```

Then I type `ios_webkit_proxy_debug`to get the proxy running. Everything in the terminal goes fine - no errors. When I go to `localhost:9221`, I get an error saying Chrome could not connect.

Here's an image of my browser, terminal, and ios simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB5QT.png

Anyone have any suggestions or know what's going on?